# Copy/pasting information from one opened workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm here again with another puzzling question.

For the last week, ive been struggling with coding a user form to copy/paste cell information from one workbook sheet to another (Both are opened). Here's how the program Im creating works:

I have a userform that allows the viewer to look up patient files that were created on excel. Through the use of a listbox, the listbox reveals the inputed patients records, files, etc that are within their specific patient folder. Using listbox_click(), this opens that particular excel file *which is coded to to hide using Thisworkbook.application.visible = False*. Now a second userform appears that shows the progression of what the program is doing, and part of this progression is the userform copy and pasting information from one open workbook *the one that was just opened* to the main workbook *the workbook that is running these userforms*. This is where im getting stuck.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim SPATH As String

    ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False
    Workbooks("oral project3.8.xlsm").Activate

    SPATH = Sheet2.Range("C5") & Sheet2.Range("G5") & Sheet2.Range("AD9") & ".xlsm"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:00"))
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Loading Data..."
    UserForm1.Repaint

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Re-Configuring Data..."
    UserForm1.Repaint

        UserForm4.TextBox9.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox8.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox7.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox6.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox5.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox4.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox3.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox22.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox21.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox20.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox19.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox18.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox17.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox16.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox15.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox14.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox13.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox12.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox11.Enabled = False
        UserForm4.TextBox10.Enabled = False

        Workbooks(SPATH).Sheet2.Range("A3").Copy
        Workbooks("oral project3.8.xlsm").Sheets("PrintOut page 1").Range("A3").PasteSpecial


    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Converting Results..."
    UserForm1.Repaint
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Loading Tables..."
    UserForm1.Repaint
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Loading Charts..."
    UserForm1.Repaint

    Workbooks(SPATH).Close

    ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False
    Workbooks("oral project3.8.xlsm").Activate

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Opening..."
    UserForm1.Repaint
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

    Unload UserForm10
    UserForm8.Show
End Sub
```

It keeps producing the run time error "9" saying the subscript is out of range when the vba reaches (Workbooks(SPATH).sheet2.range("A3").copy), but I defined the workbook using SPATH above, so I don't know what could be the issue.

***[UPDATE]-*** Ok so I just discovered a potentially reason behind the error. SPATH, when written out, is suppose to be FirstnameLastnameDate, so using myself as an example: TimBabine08-02-2018.

However, when I put my cursor over the SPATH in the highlighted code that produces the error, it reads 12:00:00am.xlsm. This is probably the issue, because the workbook I want to copy from is named TimBabine08-02-2018. However, as you're probably aware, I cant save a workbook using the former because excel will treat it as a path, hence why I have the cell with the date formatted for date: mm-dd-yyyy. however, I still don't know how to fix the problem. I tried Sheet2.range("AD9").NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy" But SPATH comes up as 12:00:00am.xlsm.

Comment: you can't specify a worksheet like `sheet2.`. Assuming you want to access the second sheet, you'd replace that with `Sheets(2).`

Comment: I changed it like you suggested but it still produces the error

Comment: See [UPDATE] in OP

Comment: it doesn't appear to be updated... what i'm saying is that `Sheet2.range("AD9")` should become `Sheets(2).range("AD9")`

Comment: @marcucciboy2 as I mentioned before, the error still occurs even when changing it to Sheets(2), and the path still reads the same result whether its sheet2 ro sheets(2)